# prime numbers in python same programs different outputs

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, primes, indentation

I have this assignment where I have to write a code to determine if a number is a prime number or not and I couldn't come up with a solution so I searched the net and found the following code( the first one) and then I wrote the exact same code but with a different name and it didn't work for numbers like 65, 75, ... and said they are prime numbers, while they aren't.
Can you help me find out what I'm doin wrong!
thank you in advance!

The code I copied:

```
    num=int(input())
if num > 1:
    for i in range(2, int(num/2)+1):
        if (num % i) == 0:
            print(num, "is not a prime number")
            break
    else:
        print(num, "is a prime number")
  
else:
    print(num, "is not a prime number")
```

my code:

```
addad=int(input())
if addad>1:
    for i in range(2,int(addad/2)+1):
        if (addad%i)==0:
            print("not prime")
            break
        else:
            print("prime")
            break
else:
    print("prime")
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work because your indentation of the `else` block should be on the same level as the for loop.

Comment: Your code is different to the first snippet.

Comment: These two code examples are NOT the same. Indentation makes a big difference in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not same.

In the above code you use `for...else` but in the second you used `if...else`. Take a closer look at the indentations. White space has great significance in python.

I think you might need to read a little about [for/else](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html) in python. You will find the difference for sure.

little description, `else` in the same indent with `for` will run if the `for` loop goes to the end(no breaks). so in the first snippet `else` will run at the end of the `for` with condition of no breaks happening, while in the code that you write `else` is IN the `for` block and will run in each cycle and it is bind to the `if` command above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I really need to do as you said and study for... else again because I think the program should still work the way I wrote it(which is clearly wrong :D ).

Comment: Sure, Just little description added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

here's one way to do it, note that 1 is not a prime number:

```
def check_prime(x):
    if x >= 2:
        for y in range(2,x):
            if not (x % y):
                return 'not prime'
    else:
        return 'not prime'
    return 'prime'

check_prime(int(input('Enter number to check: ')))
```

Output:

```
Enter number to check:  31
'prime'
```

Comment: Thank you for answering me! But I still don't know how to work with if not :)